# Size of on disk cached RDD keeps on growing in spark

Tags: apache-spark

In my spark job, I am caching some dataset and storing it as globalTempview using createOrReplaceGlobalTempView. And subsequently use this dataset to join with other smaller dataset. I am using default caching which is persist memory and disk. But I am seeing strange issue with caching.

When the job starts the cache size is as expected but as time passes the storage size reported by spark ui keeps on increasing.

Below is the view when the job is running for 1 hour

| Block Name | Storage Level | Size in Memory | Size on Disk |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| rdd_58_0 | Disk Serialized 2x Replicated | 0.0 B | 7.6 GiB |
| rdd_58_1 | Disk Serialized 2x Replicated | 0.0 B | 10.2 GiB |
| rdd_58_10 | Disk Serialized 2x Replicated | 0.0 B | 5.1 GiB |
| rdd_58_11 | Disk Serialized 1x Replicated | 0.0 B | 7.6 GiB |
| rdd_58_12 | Disk Serialized 1x Replicated | 0.0 B | 10.2 GiB |
| rdd_58_13 | Disk Serialized 1x Replicated | 0.0 B | 12.7 GiB |
| rdd_58_14 | Disk Serialized 1x Replicated | 0.0 B | 10.2 GiB |
| rdd_58_15 | Disk Serialized 1x Replicated | 0.0 B | 7.6 GiB |
| rdd_58_16 | Disk Serialized 1x Replicated | 0.0 B | 2.5 GiB |
| rdd_58_17 | Disk Serialized 2x Replicated | 0.0 B | 7.6 GiB |
| rdd_58_18 | Disk Serialized 1x Replicated | 0.0 B | 2.5 GiB |
| rdd_58_19 | Disk Serialized 1x Replicated | 0.0 B | 5.1 GiB |
| rdd_58_2 | Disk Serialized 2x Replicated | 0.0 B | 5.1 GiB |
| rdd_58_20 | Disk Serialized 1x Replicated | 0.0 B | 2.5 GiB |
| rdd_58_21 | Disk Serialized 1x Replicated | 0.0 B | 7.6 GiB |
| rdd_58_22 | Disk Serialized 1x Replicated | 0.0 B | 2.5 GiB |
| rdd_58_23 | Disk Serialized 1x Replicated | 0.0 B | 7.6 GiB |
| rdd_58_24 | Disk Serialized 1x Replicated | 0.0 B | 5.1 GiB |
| rdd_58_25 | Disk Serialized 1x Replicated | 0.0 B | 7.6 GiB |
| rdd_58_26 | Disk Serialized 1x Replicated | 0.0 B | 5.1 GiB |
| rdd_58_27 | Disk Serialized 1x Replicated | 0.0 B | 2.5 GiB |
| rdd_58_28 | Disk Serialized 1x Replicated | 0.0 B | 7.6 GiB |
| rdd_58_29 | Disk Serialized 1x Replicated | 0.0 B | 2.5 GiB |
| rdd_58_3 | Disk Serialized 2x Replicated | 0.0 B | 15.3 GiB |
| rdd_58_4 | Disk Serialized 2x Replicated | 0.0 B | 20.3 GiB |
| rdd_58_5 | Disk Serialized 2x Replicated | 0.0 B | 7.6 GiB |
| rdd_58_6 | Disk Serialized 2x Replicated | 0.0 B | 15.3 GiB |
| rdd_58_7 | Disk Serialized 2x Replicated | 0.0 B | 12.7 GiB |
| rdd_58_8 | Disk Serialized 2x Replicated | 0.0 B | 7.6 GiB |
| rdd_58_9 | Disk Serialized 2x Replicated | 0.0 B | 7.6 GiB |

below is when it has been running for 5-6 hours

| Block Name | Storage Level | Size in Memory | Size on Disk |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| rdd_58_0 | Disk Serialized 2x Replicated | 0.0 B | 81.7 GiB |
| rdd_58_1 | Disk Serialized 3x Replicated | 0.0 B | 82.5 GiB |
| rdd_58_10 | Disk Serialized 2x Replicated | 0.0 B | 54.2 GiB |
| rdd_58_11 | Disk Serialized 1x Replicated | 0.0 B | 41.3 GiB |
| rdd_58_12 | Disk Serialized 2x Replicated | 0.0 B | 75.9 GiB |
| rdd_58_13 | Disk Serialized 2x Replicated | 0.0 B | 49.2 GiB |
| rdd_58_14 | Disk Serialized 2x Replicated | 0.0 B | 62.5 GiB |
| rdd_58_15 | Disk Serialized 2x Replicated | 0.0 B | 61.7 GiB |
| rdd_58_16 | Disk Serialized 1x Replicated | 0.0 B | 27.9 GiB |
| rdd_58_17 | Disk Serialized 1x Replicated | 0.0 B | 32.1 GiB |
| rdd_58_18 | Disk Serialized 3x Replicated | 0.0 B | 95.1 GiB |
| rdd_58_19 | Disk Serialized 3x Replicated | 0.0 B | 97.5 GiB |
| rdd_58_2 | Disk Serialized 3x Replicated | 0.0 B | 92.5 GiB |
| rdd_58_20 | Disk Serialized 2x Replicated | 0.0 B | 51.7 GiB |
| rdd_58_21 | Disk Serialized 3x Replicated | 0.0 B | 75.1 GiB |
| rdd_58_22 | Disk Serialized 2x Replicated | 0.0 B | 45.9 GiB |
| rdd_58_23 | Disk Serialized 3x Replicated | 0.0 B | 67.5 GiB |
| rdd_58_24 | Disk Serialized 3x Replicated | 0.0 B | 55.0 GiB |
| rdd_58_25 | Disk Serialized 2x Replicated | 0.0 B | 56.7 GiB |
| rdd_58_26 | Disk Serialized 3x Replicated | 0.0 B | 72.5 GiB |
| rdd_58_27 | Disk Serialized 3x Replicated | 0.0 B | 40.0 GiB |
| rdd_58_28 | Disk Serialized 2x Replicated | 0.0 B | 53.3 GiB |
| rdd_58_29 | Disk Serialized 2x Replicated | 0.0 B | 34.2 GiB |
| rdd_58_3 | Disk Serialized 1x Replicated | 0.0 B | 30.0 GiB |
| rdd_58_4 | Disk Serialized 2x Replicated | 0.0 B | 67.6 GiB |
| rdd_58_5 | Disk Serialized 3x Replicated | 0.0 B | 65.0 GiB |
| rdd_58_6 | Disk Serialized 2x Replicated | 0.0 B | 69.6 GiB |
| rdd_58_7 | Disk Serialized 2x Replicated | 0.0 B | 78.4 GiB |
| rdd_58_8 | Disk Serialized 3x Replicated | 0.0 B | 102.5 GiB |
| rdd_58_9 | Disk Serialized 1x Replicated | 0.0 B | 18.8 GiB |

Below is the code i am using

```
protected void loadDataSet() {   //<- called only once
someDataSet.createOrReplaceGlobalTempView(USER_DETAILS_GLOBAL_VIEW);
}

protected Dataset<Row> joinWithAccountToUserIdMap(Dataset<Row> secondDataSet) { //<- called multiple times during an application lifecycle.
    Dataset<Row> userDetails = sparkSession.table( "global_temp." + USER_DETAILS_GLOBAL_VIEW);
    final Dataset<Row> joinedDataset = secondDataSet.join(userDetails, secondDataSet.col("userid").equalTo(userDetails.col("account_id")));
    return joinedDataset;
}
```

The only important thing to note i guess this that since executors can die during 5-6 hour duration, some partitions may be reloaded from source. would that cause this behaviour? the problem I am facing because of this is that my job would die with "no disk space left issue". **Note** I am seeing steady increase even when the executors have not died.

similar question is asked
[Spark DataFrame cache keeps growing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55601779/spark-dataframe-cache-keeps-growing), but there size is increasing because of increase in replication factor.